# Math.pow(x,y) isnt working when used with document.getElementById('z').value

Tags: javascript, html

Was trying to use `Math.pow(x,y)` on two values inputted in an HTML tag, for some reason it ain't working.

```html
Input1: <input id="input1"> Input2: <input id="input2">

<button onlick="myFunction()">Click Me!</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
     var x = document.getElementById('input1').value;
     var y = document.getElementById('input2').value;
     var z = Math.pow(x, y);
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = +z;
}
</script>
```

Comment: @Carlos1232 no, that is false.

Comment: It's "onclick" not "onlick", I would not use a lickable computer interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had a typo in your `onclick` handler attribute. It should be "`onclick`" not "`onlick`". Also, you should add the `type="number"` attribute to your `input`s so that users can't enter non-numbers. Furthermore, you should explicitly parse the input values into integers using the `parseInt` function rather than relying on JS's implicit conversions. Full working example:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var xText = document.getElementById('input1').value;
  var yText = document.getElementById('input2').value;
  var xNum = parseInt(xText, 10);
  var yNum = parseInt(yText, 10);
  var z = Math.pow(xNum, yNum);
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = z;
}
```

```html
Input1: <input id="input1" type="number">
Input2: <input id="input2" type="number">

<button onclick="myFunction()">Click Me!</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: The `Math.pow()` function converts its inputs to numbers implicitly.

Comment: @JohnDoe if my answer solved your problem please accept it by clicking on the green checkmark underneath the answer score, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's `onclick` and not `onlick` which you had mistakenly typed in your code. Do note that you would get `NaN` as the output if either of the input by user is not in integer format.

So, you can either mention `type = 'Number'` while taking input explicitly or make a check function which would give an error prompt to user if the input is not a number. I have included a format check function in the demo below.

The below code works after the correction -

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  Input1: <input id="input1"> Input2: <input id="input2">


  <button onclick="myFunction()">Click Me!</button>

  <p id="demo"></p>

  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      var x = document.getElementById('input1').value;
      var y = document.getElementById('input2').value;
      if (isNaN(x) || isNaN(y)) {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 'Wrong input format';
      } else {
        var z = Math.pow(x, y);
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = +z;
      }

    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @JohnDoe yea, no problem. If any of the answer helped you mark it as accepted by clicking the green tick.